# compositions in haskell - way of working

Tags: haskell

I can't understand way of working composition in haskell,
for example:

`((.) . (+)) 3 (*2) 9 = 9 * 2 + 3 = 21`
This answer is generated by ghci.
For me, it should be:
`((.) . (+)) 3 (*2) 9 = (3+9) * 2`
Similarily, I can't understand why type of `((.) . (+))` is `Num c => c -> (a -> c) -> a -> c`

Can you try to explain it me ?

Comment: Show your reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression, `(.)` is applied to two arguments, `(.)` again and `(+)`. Let's take it one step at a time. First, partially apply `(.)` to `(.)`. We'll write the type signatures down explicitly, using different type variables to distinguish between the two:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) :: (t -> u) -> (s -> t) -> s -> u
```

Now look at the type of `(.) (.)` (the partial application). (This is probably the trickiest step, due to the size of the type expressions involved. The next step is the same, but with simpler types.) The first argument, of type `(b -> c)`, is unified with `(t -> u) -> (s -> t) -> s -> u`, meaning

```
b ~ t -> u
c ~ (s -> t) -> s -> u
```

When we do the partial application, we drop the first argument to `(.)` (since we've given it a value) and look at the type after replacing the remaining `b`s and `c`s with their new types.

```
(.)     :: (b -> c) -> (a ->    b   )  -> a ->          c
(.) (.) ::             (a -> (t -> u)) -> a -> ((s -> t) -> s -> u)
```

Because `->` is right-associative, we can drop some of the excess parentheses to get

```
(.) (.) ::             (a -> t -> u) -> a -> (s -> t) -> s -> u
```

Now, we apply *that* to `(+) :: Num v => v -> v -> v` (again, using a new type variable for clarity). The first argument of `(.) (.)` has type `a -> t -> u`, which we need to unify with `v -> v -> v`. In other words, we'll replace all occurrences of `a`, `t`, and `u` in `(.) (.)`'s type with `v`

```
(.) (.)     :: (a -> t -> u) -> a -> (s -> t) -> s -> u 
(.) (.) (+) ::                  v -> (s -> v) -> s -> v
```

And as you can see (after we add the `Num v` constraint back), this is equivalent to the type you see:

```
-- v ~ c, s ~ a
Num v => v -> (s -> v) -> s -> v 
Num c => c -> (a -> c) -> a -> c
```

---

As for the actual expression being evaluated,

```
((.) . (+)) 3 (*2) 9
```

keep in mind the definition of `(.)`

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

and work from left to right. First, `(.) . (+)` is applied to `3`.

```
((.) . (+)) 3 == (.) ((+) 3)
              == (.) (3 +)
```

This partial application of `.` is applied to `(* 2)`:

```
(.) (3 +) (* 2) == (3 +) . (* 2)
                == \x -> (3 +) ((* 2) x)
```

Finally, this function is applied to 9:

```
(\x -> (3 +) ((* 2) x)) 9 == (3 +) ((* 2) 9)
                          == (3 +) (9 * 2)
                          == 3 + 9 * 2
                          == 3 + 18
                          == 21
```

Comment: I don;t know ont thing now, how does it work unification , I mean from what you know `that (b -> c), is unified with (t -> u) -> (s -> t) -> s -> u`